AWS SAM YAML Template: Lambda invoke policy
I'm trying to add into an AWS lambda (called UploadTriggerFunction), a policy to invoke another lambda (called EmoryParserFunction) in my template.yaml for AWS SAM.
When I do sam deploy, it's failing due to an error in the mentioned policy. I've searched in the internet and I can't find a solution.
This is the resource that I have so far (yaml code):
UploadTriggerFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  CodeUri: src/upload_trigger/
  Policies:
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref DocumentTable
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref MemoryTable
    - S3ReadPolicy:
        BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}*"
    - SQSSendMessagePolicy:
        QueueName: !GetAtt EmbeddingQueue.QueueName
    - Statement:
        - Sid: "LambdaInvokePermission"
          Action: "lambda:*"
          FunctionName: !Ref EmoryParserFunction
          Principal: "*"

This is the error when I do sam deploy --guided:
UPDATE_FAILED                    AWS::IAM::Role                   UploadTriggerFunctionRole        Resource handler returned      
                                                                                               message: "Syntax errors in     
                                                                                               policy. (Service: Iam, Status  
                                                                                               Code: 400, Request ID: 67a2b4d 
                                                                                               6-4efd-483e-9a20-              
                                                                                               290b983f3521)" (RequestToken:  
                                                                                               afebd2d9-cc06-70e2-ba50-       
                                                                                               5dca6751f288,                  
                                                                                               HandlerErrorCode:              
                                                                                               InvalidRequest)    

Question: anybody knows how to add that permission?

Is that the exact formatting of your YAML? The second line should be indented compared to the first line. Or is it just a Copy & Paste error?

Which line is causing the error? Is it the Statement at the bottom? (You can check by removing it to see whether this removes the error.) It doesn't seem to match the example on AWS::Serverless::Function - AWS Serverless Application Model.
